# jquery selecting nth-child skipping hidden elements

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have the following html structure:

```
<ul class="products">
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I having the following jquery:

```
$(".products li:nth-child(4)").addClass("last");
```

As you can see the above will add a class of last to every 4th `<li>`.

However in my HTML there might be a hidden `<li>` using `display:none;` via jquery.

Is there a way to skip past the hidden elements? So in theory i should have the following:

```
<ul class="products">
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li style="display:none;"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: look at this http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: have you looked into .not()?

Comment: `:visible` and `:not()` won't affect `:nth-child()`. I'm afraid you will have to `each()` your way modulo 4 out of that one.

Comment: Your conclusion of how this selector works is incorrect. It will not select every 4th li inside an element of class products; it will select ONLY  the 4th li.

Comment: @jeff, okay, but let's assume the questioner meant `4n`. Element visibility still would not be taken into account.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Correct, I was just pointing out, perhaps prevent a future issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply limit your selection to exclude hidden items:

```
$('.products li').filter(':visible');
```

Unfortunately you can't use nth selectors here, since you don't want to count the hidden elements., so you could just iterate over the items and change every fourth one.

```
$('.products li').filter(':visible').each(function(i) {
    var modulus = (i + 1) % 4;
    if (modulus === 0) { 
        $(this).addClass('last');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could try using the index instead of using a selector of nth child, along with lorenzos solution?

```
$('li:visible').each(function(i){
    if((i+1) % 4 == 0){
        $(this).addClass('temp');
    }
});
```

UPDATED [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/R5UNg/2/)

Comment: I downvoted. This adds the class to only the 4th visible item, not to 8th, 12th, 16th... etc

Comment: Fixed, mind a quick upvote? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$('.products li:visible').filter(function(index){
    return !((index+1) % 4);
}).addClass('last')
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/egQp7/

Comment: More or less same as the answer I had given. I would just comment that using `:visible` as part of the initial selector is an expensive operation, you should really, make a CSS-based selector and then use `filter()` on it to determine the visible elements. You could obviously just chain two `filter()` calls in a row to achieve this.

Comment: Didnt know about that, but yeah, perfomance side, your answer is better!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your first selector select only visible elements, then use the jquery `each()` function's index to do some quick math and find every 4th element. [A working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/3Zr2k/2/)

jquery:

```
$(".products li:visible").each(function(hiya){
    if((hiya+1) % 4 == 0){
        $(this).addClass('last');
    }
});
```

### EDIT

Took out an unnecessary logical operator.